# How to convert APNG into WEBP by using Magick.NET (imagemagick) and C#?

Tags: c#, imagemagick, imagemagick-convert, apng, imagemagick.net

I have tried like this but APNG animation is lost

Also I am looking for settings to lossless yet maximum compression. I don't care about CPU time speed etc. I need lossless and maximum compression. how to achieve that?

So I have a lot of PNG files and some APNG files

I will turn all of them into WEBP files

Yet I still want to keep APNG animation as well

Here example APNG to test : https://static.pokemonpets.com/images/npcTrainers/trainer15125down.png

```
     using (var image = new MagickImage(@"path\Debug\a.png"))
        {
            image.Quality = 100;
            image.Settings.SetDefine(MagickFormat.WebP, "lossless", true);
            image.Settings.SetDefine(MagickFormat.WebP, "method", "6");
            image.Write("a.webp");
        }
```

C# .net framework 4.8, Magick.NET-Q16-AnyCPU, 7.24.1.0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to read an image that contains multiple frames you will need to use the `MagickImageCollection` instead:

```
using (var images = new MagickImageCollection(@"apng:path\Debug\a.png"))
{
    var defines = new WebPWriteDefines
    {
        Lossless = true,
        Method = 6,
    };

    images.Write("a.webp", defines);
}
```

And if you want to read an animated PNG file you will need to have `ffmpeg.exe` in your `%PATH%`. This is required to read an animated PNG file. And you will also need to add `apng:` to make sure that ImageMagick knows that it is an animated PNG file.

Comment: ty for answer but still lacking. it requires to initialize like this :       FileInfo img_apng = new FileInfo(srWorkingDirectory + @"\test\trainer15202down.png");
            using (var images = new MagickImageCollection(img_apng, MagickFormat.APng))